# Mapview ping icon not Refresh

Tags: android, google-maps

I have working on GoogleMap and fount strange issue,  below is my code

```
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();  
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();        
        final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);   

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg" + " ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(7), 2000, null);
```

GoogleMap show well, issue is when FragmentActivity load, then not able to show ping location with icon, its display  when screen orientation is changed, also i have checked for `postInvalidate()`, or `Invalidate();` methods of  `GoogleMap` but not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I exactly umderstand what you are trying to say but if you want to change the location of a marker you already placed you need to remove the marker and add a new one to the map with the new location

Comment: i dont know what a ping icon is